# Calling Javascript in Wordpress functions.php not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to use the following javascript to restrict a field on my registration form to accept only numbers:

```
<script language="javascript">
function forceNumber(event){
var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode;
if((keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 58) && keyCode != 8 && keyCode != 9 && keyCode != 32 && keyCode != 37     && keyCode != 39 && keyCode != 40 && keyCode != 41 && keyCode != 43 && keyCode != 45 && keyCode != 46)
return false;
}
</script>
```

I first just added the code to the top of functions.php.  It worked but gave me an "cannot modify header information" error.

I looked into it further and saved it as  forceNumber.js and attempted to call it in functions.php using the wp_enqueue function which is supposed to be the normative way of calling it like so:

```
function forceNumber() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'force-number',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/forceNumber.js', array( 'jquery' )
);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'forceNumber' );
```

This did not work at all, even though this is how the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) suggests to do it.  When I check it out with Firebug the javascript is not even being called in the header (?!).  So no wonder it is not working.  I just don't understand how the js is not being called correctly.

Thanks and kind regards,
Helena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about possibly re-installing as I did not want to comb through code to see where Wordpress would have added the code mentioned.  However, that appears to not have been the problem.  The solution is here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103456/javascript-on-registration-page/103459?noredirect=1#103459

Answer (score 0):

In your .js-file, you have to remove the html-tags < script language="javascript"> and < /script>.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I removed the html tags but the script is still not being pulled into the head of the document.

Comment: That's odd. I copypasted your code without changing into a template of my own - and it works as it should.

Comment: Wordpress adds a line <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/(wordpress)/wp-content/themes/(theme)/js/forceNumber.js?ver=3.5.1'></script> ... If you are sure it's still not there, check at first all URLs, and if they are correct check if some plugins or such are making trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the response John.  Let me investigate this further and I'll get back to you.  Where does it add that particular line?